# Mnemonics for learning Hangul?

Tags: writing-system, electronic-resources, korean, physical-resources

I have just started learning Korean in an online course and I'm looking for resources that use **mnemonics for [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul)** or Hangeul, so I can learn the writing system in less time.

Are any such resources available? Digital or in print?

Comment: P:erhaps someone knows whether this is true: I was told that the shape of the consonants relates to the place and manner of articulation of the consonant.

Answer (score 6):

**Ryan Estrada's [Learn to Read Korean in 15 Minutes](http://www.ryanestrada.com/learntoreadkoreanin15minutes/)** uses mnemonics. For example, for the consonants:

- ㅂ looks like a bucket and is pronounced 'b' (the first consonant in 'bucket);
- ㅁ looks like a map and is pronounced 'm';
- ㄹ looks like a rattle snake and is pronounced 'r'.

For the vowels, he start with

- ㅣ, which looks like a tr**ee**;
- ㅡ, which looks like a br**oo**k.

He builds up the rest of the writing system from basics like these. The page is available under the Creative Commons Attribution Non-Commercial Share-Alike licence (CC BY-NC-SA).

The German blog post **[Koreanisch lesen lernen in 30 Minuten](http://koreanisch-lernen.net/koreanisch-lesen-lernen-in-30-minuten/)** contains a partial list of mnemonics. Curiously, some are based on German, while some are based on English.

Comment: Somebody clarified the comic at: http://www.beyondthezebra.com/learn-the-korean-alphabet-in-about-fifteen-minutes/

Answer (score 4):

This is a YouTube video titled [Learn to Read Korean in 5 Minutes (seriously)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TE4eplsFSms); it covers the vast majority of the symbols that compose Hangul in a short and easy to understand format.

Answer (score 1):

The introduction of the textbook "Integrated Korean: Beginning 1" by Cho et al. is a useful academic resource for picking up mnemonics for some letters, especially the letters whose shapes correspond to human anatomy used for speech.

Most usefully, the authors wrote that: "Consonant letters originally depicted the speech organs that produce consonant sounds: the lips, tooth, tongue, and throat." Therefore, they wrote that (from page 25):

- ㅁ (mieum) is pronounced as "m" because the shape is similar to a mouth with closed lips
- ㄴ (nieun) is pronounced as "n" because it is the shape of one's tongue touching the ridge of one's upper gum
- ㅅ (siot) is pronounced as "s" because it looks like a tooth, which is used to make hissing sounds
- ㄱ (giyeok) is pronounced as "k/g" because it is the shape of one's tongue touching one's soft palate to make the "k/g" sound
- ㅇ (ng) is pronounced as "ng" because the sound comes from one's throat, which looks circular when looking down one's throat

This learning approach may be particularly helpful to beginners, as it takes a historical perspective that demonstrates the "why" behind the development of some of the letter shapes for Hangul.